# Generate a final class from -items.xml in Hybris

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

Final class in java means its not extendable by any other class. How do we do it in hybris while defining data-model in -Items.xml ?

Comment: why especially you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAP Hybris platform does not support generation of the `final` data-model classes OOTB (Out Of The Box). You cannot override that mechanism, but you are allowed to modify generated class located in the `src` directory. If you want a `final` data-model class (e.g. Foo), you can manually add this modifier.

```
<itemtypes>
    <itemtype code="Foo" jaloclass="org.example.Foo">
        <attributes>
            <!-- attributes -->
        </attributes>
    </itemtype>
</itemtypes>
```

File structure:

- `src/org/example/Foo` ← you can mark this class as `final`
- `gensrc/org/example/GeneratedFoo` ← you cannot modify this class

(class `Foo` extends `GeneratedFoo`)

All extensions with types which extend `Foo` will fail during build phase.

---

SAP Hybris platform allows only to set an `abstract` modifier by using an `abstract` attribute equal to `true`:

```
<itemtypes>
    <itemtype code="Foo" abstract="true">
        <attributes>
            <!-- attributes -->
        </attributes>
    </itemtype>
</itemtypes>
```

Comment: Those generated files are placed in the `src` directory to allow developers to add additional behavior. Whether a modification is good or bad depends on the type of change. I think that adding `final` modifier is not a good change, but it is possible.